# How to enclose an Angular 2 Module in a sandbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to allow dynamic loading of NgModules in my Angular 2 application. The idea is that other developers might add some sort of plugins to it, that will add some new routes and show new components. Ideally they will be added through the router with lazy loading. The basic idea seems to be working but the one thing I would like to add is some sort of a sandbox.

It is possible that those plugins will throw some exceptions. I don't want them to mess with the main application. I tried defining separate Error Handlers for those modules, but the Error Handler for the main module seems to overwrite them. Now I wonder if I should use the loadChildren function from lazy loading to create my own NgModuleFactory to surround those dynamic NgModules in some sort of gigant try-catch clause.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Hi. Defining Error Handlers per module seems a valid approach. Could you describe what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Hi. Basically I just defined a different Error Handlers in different modules, using  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MainModuleErrorHandler} or  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: OtherModuleErrorHandler} in module definitions but only the one from the bootstrap module seems to be used.
Sorry for such a late response.